# MySQL query using Excel

Tags: mysql, excel

I am writing a MySQL script in VBA to extract data from my database.

Is it possible to pass a list of criteria to a MySQL statement in excel ??

For example lets my script (using VBA) is as follows

select * from farms where date = '20180101' and 
(animals like 'cat', 
or animals like 'dog'
or animals like 'horse')

Now lets say i have 200 animals and they are in an excel list or in a spreadsheet , is it possible to reference the list (like a lookup) instead of writing a very lengthy script ??

Comment: There is the IN operator, but won't shorten query that much. Why not select them all and match up using VBA?

Comment: Yeah that may be my only option but i wonder if  i could use the IN operator and have the criteria (the 200 animals) in an excel column and point the MySQL script to this column ?

Comment: nothing I know of. ODBC is probably used by excel which (used to?) put a 32Kb limit on query strings.  That should be plenty for 200 animals but for 1000, not so much.